# Save bidimensional Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am doing a Bingo program. I need to save the `bingoCard` (bidimensional array), because every time I execute a new move the card is different. And it need to be the same.

So I need to know how to save the card. I have a global variable (`private static int[][]bingoCard=new int[3][9];`) this is the code

```
public static int[][] bingoCard(){
    int numRows = 3;
    int numCols = 9;
    int randomNumbersPerRow = 5;
    int randomNumberBound = 90;

    Random random = new Random();
    bingoCard = new int[numRows][numCols];
    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
            bingoCard[row][col] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbersPerRow; i++) {
            int indexToAssign = random.nextInt(numCols);
            while (bingoCard[row][indexToAssign] != 0) {
                indexToAssign = random.nextInt(numCols);
            }
            int numToAssign = random.nextInt(randomNumberBound)+1;
            bingoCard[row][indexToAssign] = numToAssign;
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", bingoCard[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return bingoCard;
}
```

Comment: The solution is to only call your `bingoCard` method once. "I need to save the bingoCard" is already done because you write to the static class field `bingoCard`, where the data from your method is saved.

Comment: Your design with a static method with that much business logic and a global variable is not object oriented - just in case you wanted to achieve OOD ;)